# how to distribute points in each sub-square of a large sqaure in a plane with a given node density in matlab

Tags: matlab

In an area of 200 x 200, I am able to generate small square grids (4x4). But I want to distribute 20 points using Poisson Distribution.
But the problem I encountered id some point coordinates fall out the area. How can I confine the 20 points (Cartesian coordinates) inside the region under study. Can anyone help me out.
I want to generate 10 different nodes distribution for 20 nodes in `matlab`.
Please give me an idea.

Comment: I'd say you have two options : 1/ You iterate until you find a valid distribution.2/ You find a "trick" to handle to points that are out of bounds. (For example using finite groups)

Comment: @BillBokeey, if you iterate until you find a valid distribution you don't respect the poisson distribution, the probabilities change !

Comment: Well, as the Poisson's distribution doesn't have a finite support, any solution will be biased...